# JS. Доступ к переменной в модуле из внешнего кода

Tags: javascript, typescript, модули

Использую TypeScript, написал некий файл по инициализации класса + загрузке начальных параметров.

```
import PageContainer from './Page/pages';
import {Animation} from "./Page/pages";

export var pageContainer = new PageContainer('container', new Animation('', ''));
pageContainer.select('Sign In');
```

Далее я все это дело собираю вебпаком и подключаю вот так в html:

```
<script src="../../out/bundle.js"></script>
```

Вопрос в том, как сделать этот самый `pageContainer` доступным в этом html файле? Чтобы вот такой код, например: `<a href="javascript: pageContainer.switch('Sign Up')">Register</a>` смог заработать?

Comment: Старая добрая запись в глобальный объект window.pageContainer = .... Другой вопрос откуда "вот такой вот код" взялся, если его кто-то написал сам ручками (а не какая-то тулза сгенерила) то так делать в общем не оч, в нормального размера приложениях по крайней мере.

Comment: Спасибо ) Хм, а как лучше делать? Мне просто показалось, прямо в html довольно наглядно получается

Comment: Для очень маленького приложения пойдет в общем. Для маленького но которое будет расти можно что-то типа <a class="js-tab-switch"> и на объекты с таким классом навешать обработчик где-то при инициализации приложения. Для нормального или рискующего вырасти лучше взять готовый роутер. Цель этих плясок - изолировать логику от представления. В том числе и глобальных переменных поменьше клепать

Comment: Ага, я вас понял, спасибо большое )